# Adding Fragment through dependency injection

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I have an activity with just one fragment and how I am creating a fragment is by creating a newInstance.

Is this the right approach, should I be doing this using dependency injection - Dagger, if so could you suggest how can I do this please

I have a companionObject in my Fragment which does the newInstance of the fragment

### MainActivity

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
        @Inject
        lateinit var mainActivityViewModel: MainActivityViewModel
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
            setupFragment()
        }
    
        private fun setupFragment() {
            val mainActivityViewModel = DaggerRetroComponent.create().getMainActivityViewModel()
            val fragment = CreditScoreFragment.newInstance(mainActivityViewModel)
            val fragmentManager: FragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
            val fragmentTransaction: FragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment)
            fragmentTransaction.commit()
        }
    }
```

### Fragment

```
class CreditScoreFragment @Inject constructor(
    private val viewModel: MainActivityViewModel
) : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentCreditScoreBinding? = null

    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentCreditScoreBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val view = binding.root
        initViewModel()
        initView()
        return view
    }

    private fun initViewModel() {
        viewModel.getCreditReportObserver().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer<CreditReport> {
            showScoreUI(true)
            binding.score.text = it.creditReportInfo.score.toString()
            binding.maxScoreValue.text = "out of ${it.creditReportInfo.maxScoreValue}"
            initDonutView(
                it.creditReportInfo.score.toFloat(),
                it.creditReportInfo.maxScoreValue.toFloat()
            )
        })
        viewModel.getServerErrorLiveDataObserver().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer<Boolean> {
            if(it) {
                showScoreUI(false)
                showToastMessage()
            }
        })
        viewModel.getCreditReport()
    }

    private fun initView() {
        binding.btnRefresh.setOnClickListener {
            viewModel.getCreditReport()
        }
    }

    private fun initDonutView(score: Float, maxScoreValue: Float) {
        val section1 = DonutSection(
            name = "section_1",
            color = Color.parseColor("#FB1D32"),
            amount = score
        )
        binding.donutView.cap = maxScoreValue
        binding.donutView.submitData(listOf(section1))
    }

    fun showScoreUI(show: Boolean) {
        binding.yourCreditScore.isVisible = show
        binding.maxScoreValue.isVisible = show
        binding.donutView.isVisible = show
        binding.score.isVisible = show
    }

    fun showToastMessage() {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Error connecting to server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(viewModel: MainActivityViewModel) =
            CreditScoreFragment(viewModel).apply {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not recommended and wouldn't accomplish much. first issue here is that every fragment class [must have a public no-args constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html), which is used by the Android system to re-instantiate the fragment when required.

second issue is that injecting a `Fragment` is going to cause more problems than it will solve. for example even if you manage to create an object of fragment, you will still have to use a fragment transaction to load the fragment in Activity.

third, that is not how you provide a `ViewModel` to a `Fragment`. in kotlin you can simply write

```
private val viewModel: MainActivityViewModel  by activityViewModels()
```

So, don't try to inject `Fragment`, and follow the recommended practices.

Comment: Hello @mightyWOZ, thanks for coming back on this, much appreciated.
1st point - fragment in an activity is done correctly and no need to make any changes.
in your 3rd point, I am injecting viewModel using dipendency injection, if i understand it correctly you are saying that what i have done is wrong

Comment: Your Fragment class doesn't have a public no-args constructor

Comment: could you tell me the code which I need to add please